# jmeter several http request reading from one csv data set config

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is it posible to have several http request read from one csv data set config?

I whant to make http request 1 to read from line 1 to 50 and http request 2 read from line 51 to 100 from the .csv file, and so on. Is this posible? or do i ahve to make more small csv files and more csv data set config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but generally not recommended. It will be much easier if smaller CSV's are used. Nevertheless you can make following changes for doing it through CSV data set config: -

1. Configure "Recycle on EOF" to False.
2. Configure "Stop thread on EOF" to False.
3. Sharing mode to "All threads".
4. Place HTTP requests in different thread group and set total number of threads to desired value. In your case the value for 1st and 2nd thread group should be 50. Also make sure that two thread groups does not start at same time. Add a startup delay for 2nd thread group.